# xmlreader, get the attribute's name

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I want to do something like:

```
stringBuilder.AppendLine("   globalVar." + reader.GetAttribute(i).Name + " = " + reader[i] + "; //add param ");
```

Where "**reader.GetAttribute(i).Name**" is the component that doesn't work. Is there an equivalent method to get the name of an attribute?

Comment: Check out [MSDN - Reading Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/by2bd43b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `reader.MoveToAttribute(i)`, then you can use `reader.Name` and `reader.Value`.

Comment: thanks this did work eventually... I had to change some logic but it did.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Name` and `Value` directly on reader - see sample from [Reading Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.movetoattribute?view=net-6.0) below:

```
if (reader.HasAttributes) {
  Console.WriteLine("Attributes of <" + reader.Name + ">");
  while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute()) {
    Console.WriteLine(" {0}={1}", reader.Name, reader.Value);
  }
  // Move the reader back to the element node.
  reader.MoveToElement();
}
```

Comment: The link for the sample has changed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.movetoattribute?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

GetAttribute() returns the string value of the attribute.  It doesn't have a "name" property.  Try to move to the attribute and then get the "Name" property.

Comment: What do you mean 'move the attribute'? I know that GetAttribute() returns the string value of the attribute... I am asking if there is a way to get the 'ids' if you will of each attribute.

Comment: I see John has the answer above.  Reader . move to attribute(i).  Them reader. Name should do it.